# VBA to search for folder or create it

Tags: excel, vba

good afternoon all, 
i am using the following code on my spreadsheet to save the file in a specific folder with a specific format:

```
Const csPath As String = "C:\Stationery Orders\"
MyName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=csPath & Sheets("Stationery").Cells(1, 1) & Format(CStr(Now), "ddmmyyyy_hhmm") & "  " & MyName & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=52
```

my problem is that i can't find a way to create this folder C:\Stationery Orders\ if the folder doesn't exist and also paste a shortcut on the user's desktop. Is that even possible? any ideas?

kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a check before doing `SaveAs`. Something like,

```
If Dir(csPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir csPath
```

Then do the `SaveAs`

Comment: thank you very much for your replies, they both work but this one is easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will check if folder exists and create it if it doesn't exist.

```
Sub MyCuteSub()
    Dim FSO
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not FSO.FolderExists("C:\temp\temptemptemp") Then
        FSO.CreateFolder ("C:\temp\temptemptemp")
    End If
End Sub
```